# Agregar elemento a columna en pandas!

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

si tengo un Dataframe con x filas y k columnas y esta organizado de la siguiente manera:

```
    k_1   k_2   k_3   k_4
0     a     b     c     d
1     e     f     g   nan
```

Si por ejemplo en la columna 2 (o otra) quisiera agregar algún(os) elemento(s) almacenado(s) en una lista por ejemplo A=['h','i']

Quisiera obtener:

```
    k_1   k_2   k_3   k_4
0     a     b     c     d
1     e     f     g   nan 
2   nan     h   nan   nan
3   nan     i   nan   nan
```

Comment: Si es necesario puedes agregar una imagen de tu dataframe para entenderlo mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los Dataframes tienen el método `append()` que admite una sintaxis en la que puedes añadir un elemento a una sola columna: `df.append({"nombre_columna": "elemento"})`. Usando esa misma sintaxis, pero pasando una lista de diccionarios en lugar de un solo diccionario, se puede agregar varios elementos a una misma columna (o a una columna diferente cada vez, según la clave del diccionario).

Así pues, para tu caso, lo siguiente podría servir:

```
A = ["h", "i"]
df.append([{"k_2": v} for v in A], ignore_index=True)
```

Y el resultado es:

```
   k_1 k_2  k_3  k_4
0    a   b    c    d
1    e   f    g  NaN
2  NaN   h  NaN  NaN
3  NaN   i  NaN  NaN
```